# Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type.

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm practicing some code, some problem brought up.

Here's the code

```
class Food {
    let name:String
    var fruits:[Fruits]?

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}


class Fruits {
    let name:String
    let capacity:Int

    init(name:String, capacity:Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.capacity = capacity
    }
}


var macFood: Food = Food(name: "macFood")
macFood.fruits
macFood.fruits = [Fruits(name: "Apple", capacity: 1), Fruits(name: "Banana", capacity: 2)]
macFood
macFood.fruits

macFood.fruits += [Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)]
```

All codes were good, printed well, but the last line brought a problem.

I thought that macFood.fruits is Array.

Because, **macFood.fruits = [Fruits(name: "Apple", capacity: 1), Fruits(name: "Banana", capacity: 2)]** worked.

So I thought that I could add another elements by using '+=' operator.

But it crashed at the last line, **macFood.fruits += [Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)]**

The error messages are

**'binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Fruits]?' and '[Fruits]'
macFood.fruits += [Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)]'**

**'expected an argument list of type '(inout R, S)'
macFood.fruits += [Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)]'**

**Question**

1. What is the reason for the crash?
2. Is macFood.fruits **Array**?

   2-1. If yes, can I add another elements in Array?

   2-2. If not, why isn't this Array?

   2-1-1. If yes and yes, how can I add another elements in Array?

   2-1-2. If yes but no, why can't I add elements in Array?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to initialize your fruits array `var fruits: [Fruits] = []`

Comment: You are trying to append an element to nil instead of appending to an empty array

Comment: *Read* the error message. `[Fruits]?` and `[Fruits]` are different types. Read about optionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reason is that you are trying to use += to two objects of different types, 
   one is array of Fruits and another is Optional ([`Fruits]?` means it
   is optional).
2. Yes, it is an array.

   2.1 Yes

   2.1.1 You can add another elements by using `yourArray.append(object)`

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question! What's the meaning of 'expected an argument list of type (inout R, S) ', especially type (inout R,S) ?

Comment: @Hoo if answer fits your question, can you tick it as correct one? According to your additional question, can you give more info? Where does that come from?

Comment: macFood.fruits! += [Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)] worked! But when I remove ! again, expected an argument list of type '(inout R, S)'
macFood.fruits += [Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)] message shows again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I overlooked it.

Your Problem is that 'macFood.fruits' is optional and you cant add an non-optional type onto a optional type.

Either you set fruits non optional like

```
var fruits:[Fruits] = []
```

Or you use the append method like:

```
    if macFood.fruits?.append(Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)) == nil {
    myArray = [Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)] 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question! What's the meaning of 'expected an argument list of type (inout R, S) ', especially type (inout R,S) ?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to Declare Food class Like this**

```
class Food {
    let name:String
    var fruits = [Fruits]()

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Fruits {
    let name:String
    let capacity:Int

    init(name:String, capacity:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity
    }
}
```

**Use**

```
let macFood: Food = Food(name: "macFood")
macFood.fruits = [Fruits(name: "Apple", capacity: 1), Fruits(name: "Banana", capacity: 2)]
macFood.fruits += [Fruits(name: "Grape", capacity: 3)]
```